# How do I hide if no value in php function

Tags: php, hide

how do i hide the whole "Conditions: " if the field is empty? i cannot seems to figure out and the code i tried are invalid

```
echo '<span class="sku">Conditions: ' . get_post_meta( $product->id, '_conditions', true ) . '</span>';
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
if(!empty(get_post_meta( $product->id, '_conditions', true ))){
    echo '<span class="sku">Conditions: ' . get_post_meta( $product->id, '_conditions', true ) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: @Chris - If the answer solved your issue, you should accept it. That will not only give the user who wrote it their well-deserved rep, it will also tell others (like me) that the question has already been solved.